# People having trouble connecting to my Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft server set up for my friends to play on. For some it works just fine, while others cannot connect. Here is what I have done to try to fix the issue:

**Port Forwarding**

I have checked the following:

1. [www.yougetsignal.com](http://www.yougetsignal.com) confirms that port 25565 is open;
2. The firewall has been turned off for both router and computer;
3. WMZ is disabled on router;
4. The IP address users are connecting to is the public IP address that I got from the above website.

**Minecraft server settings**

5. "server-ip" in `server.properties` is left blank;
6. "enforce-whitelist" is false;
7. I am running Minecraft server *minecraft_server.1.13.2.jar* from the [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net) website without any plugins installed.
8. Error shown when User tries to connect:

   ```
   UUID of player Scrub_Thug is c203e548-bd21-4355-8017-6ca1a5e2b5f8
   [19:34:31 INFO]: Scrub_Thug[/76.177.147.73:54443] logged in with entity id 926 at (43.5, 71.0, 82.5)
   [19:34:31 INFO]: Scrub_Thug joined the game
   [19:35:00 INFO]: Scrub_Thug lost connection: Timed out
   [19:35:00 INFO]: Scrub_Thug left the game
   ```

**User issues**

1. The user who can't connect to my server is able to connect to other servers;
2. One other person other than myself is able to connect to the server.

Comment: Can you join yourself from another computer? Is it always the same people who can't join? Do they have fast internet? Do you have fast internet?

Comment: @fabian doesn't MC not allow the same user to join the same game, just for technical reasons etc.? i don't understand what you mean by that first question; same network, different account?

Comment: I mean if you can join your server from your own computer with your own Minecraft account. Not twice of course. Just to verify that joining actually works. But it sounds like you already did that, so what about the other questions?

Comment: @FabianRöling internet speed is of decent quality for both of us. I think perhaps that the issue might be the loss of packets but that is just a gut feeling.

Comment: What is WMZ?I think that you misspelled DMZ (demilitarized zone).

Comment: @bogdanStefanescu lol I am 100% sure I did not mean DMZ. WMZ is a setting that allows a single computer on your LAN to open all of its ports.

Comment: Yep.. Pretty sure that's called DMZ. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)